# Why does moving a call function 1 byte earlier causes it to malfunction? What to modify to resolve it?

Tags: function, assembly, disassembly, dosbox, hex-editors

I am trying to create an inline codecave to modify a very old dosgame (ROTK2). However, far calls cannot be repositioned - moving the machine code for the function call 1 byte earlier causes it to malfunction. What parameters I need to readjust to correct the problem?

To be more specific for the task needed, I need to create 3 bytes of space to be able to add an assembly line. Hence I need to reposition code (codecaving may not be a possible option due to lack of resources in script, I had to find the 3 bytes inline).

There are too many lines of code in the whole program, which I do not fully understand, but I am using dosbox debugger with breakpoints to pinpoint to lines relevant:

This position of the code prints out the year, month and season at the current point of time in the game. From line 4EE8, the two pushs of ax moves the cursor to the position (2,4) on the screen so that the year located at [0x44] and the month, number located at bl [0x46] which then needs to be modified to reference to the month in text somewhere else. Then the string is printed out, and the process is repeated.

... 
00004EDF  0E                push cs      
00004EE0  E80500            call 0x4ee8  
00004EE3  0E                push cs      
00004EE4  E85101            call 0x5038  
00004EE7  CB                retf         
00004EE8  B80400            mov ax,0x4   
00004EEB  50                push ax      
00004EEC  B80200            mov ax,0x2   
00004EEF  50                push ax      
00004EF0  9A3404EF03        call 0x3ef:0x434 
00004EF5  83C404            add sp,byte +0x4 
00004EF8  FF364400          push word [0x44] 
00004EFC  8A1E4600          mov bl,[0x46]    
00004F00  2AFF              sub bh,bh        
00004F02  D1E3              shl bx,1         
00004F04  FFB71C36          push word [bx+0x361c] 
00004F08  B8B834            mov ax,0x34b8 
00004F0B  50                push ax 
00004F0C  9AE806EF03        call 0x3ef:0x6e8 
00004F11  83C406            add sp,byte +0x6 
00004F14  B80C00            mov ax,0xc 
00004F17  50                push ax 
00004F18  B80500            mov ax,0x5 
00004F1B  50                push ax 
00004F1C  9A3404EF03        call 0x3ef:0x434 
00004F21  83C404            add sp,byte +0x4 
00004F24  A04600            mov al,[0x46] 
00004F27  B103              mov cl,0x3 
00004F29  2AE4              sub ah,ah 
00004F2B  F6F1              div cl 
00004F2D  8AD8              mov bl,al 
00004F2F  2AFF              sub bh,bh 
00004F31  D1E3              shl bx,1 
00004F33  FFB7D634          push word [bx+0x34d6] 
00004F37  B8CC34            mov ax,0x34cc 
00004F3A  50                push ax 
00004F3B  9AE806EF03        call 0x3ef:0x6e8 
00004F40  83C404            add sp,byte +0x4 
00004F43  CB                retf 
....

I can make the code more "concise" by doing this without breaking the code: 
... 
00004EDF  0E                push cs      
00004EE0  E80500            call 0x4ee8  
00004EE3  0E                push cs      
00004EE4  E85101            call 0x5038  
00004EE7  CB                retf         
00004EE8  B80400            mov ax,0x4   
00004EEB  50                push ax      
00004EEC  D1E8              shr ax,1     
**00004EEE  50                push ax; just nice the previous number was double 

00004EEF  90                nop**          

00004EF0  9A3404EF03        call 0x3ef:0x434 
00004EF5  83C404            add sp,byte +0x4 
00004EF8  FF364400          push word [0x44] 
00004EFC  8A1E4600          mov bl,[0x46]    
00004F00  2AFF              sub bh,bh        
00004F02  D1E3              shl bx,1         
00004F04  FFB71C36          push word [bx+0x361c] 
00004F08  B8B834            mov ax,0x34b8 
00004F0B  50                push ax 
00004F0C  9AE806EF03        call 0x3ef:0x6e8 
00004F11  83C406            add sp,byte +0x6 
00004F14  B80C00            mov ax,0xc 
00004F17  50                push ax 
00004F18  B80500            mov ax,0x5 
00004F1B  50                push ax 
00004F1C  9A3404EF03        call 0x3ef:0x434 
00004F21  83C404            add sp,byte +0x4 
00004F24  A04600            mov al,[0x46] 
00004F27  B103              mov cl,0x3 
00004F29  2AE4              sub ah,ah 
00004F2B  F6F1              div cl 
00004F2D  8AD8              mov bl,al 
00004F2F  2AFF              sub bh,bh 
00004F31  D1E3              shl bx,1 
00004F33  FFB7D634          push word [bx+0x34d6] 
00004F37  B8CC34            mov ax,0x34cc 
00004F3A  50                push ax 
00004F3B  9AE806EF03        call 0x3ef:0x6e8 
00004F40  83C404            add sp,byte +0x4 
00004F43  CB                retf 
....

But once I shift the function call one byte earlier (instead of having the nop in front of the call 0x3ef:0x434 but call 0x3ef:0x434 then the nop), everything cease to function.

with nop first: dosbox logger output 
07D2:0000039F  nop 
                                              EAX:00000002 EBX:00000054 ECX:00000000 EDX:000003CF ESI:00003431 EDI:00000107 EBP:0000E424 ESP:0000E416 DS:32C3 ES:A000 FS:0000 GS:0000 SS:32C3 CF:0 ZF:0 SF:0 OF:0 AF:1 PF:0 IF:1 
07D2:000003A0  call 070C:0434 
                                   EAX:00000002 EBX:00000054 ECX:00000000 EDX:000003CF ESI:00003431 EDI:00000107 EBP:0000E424 ESP:0000E416 DS:32C3 ES:A000 FS:0000 GS:0000 SS:32C3 CF:0 ZF:0 SF:0 OF:0 AF:1 PF:0 IF:1

without nop: 
07D2:0000039F  call 20EF:0434 
                                   EAX:00000002 EBX:00000054 ECX:00000000 EDX:000003CF ESI:00003431 EDI:00000107 EBP:0000E424 ESP:0000E416 DS:32C3 ES:A000 FS:0000 GS:0000 SS:32C3 CF:0 ZF:0 SF:0 OF:0 AF:1 PF:0 IF:1

I have been reading assembly, bp, sp, ss and stuff, but I am still stuck. Hence asking the question, which is how to reposition function calls without corrupting code?

Comment: jumps and calls use relative displacements, so changing the distance between two blocks of code will break stuff if any calls cross the point where you insert padding.

Comment: That far call function appears to use absolute addressing, so I'm not sure why moving the call would be a problem, because you are not moving the position of the called routine.  The only strange thing that I could imagine happening is if the called function actually references addresses relative the the caller's return address on the stack.  Stranger things have been done in assembler.

Comment: @RufusVS: That's just the disassembly using the calculated absolute address.  x86 doesn't have absolute direct near calls, only relative.  Look at the machine code, `E80500` - that's `call rel16`

Comment: @Peter Cordes: But that is not the call he is moving.  this is the call he is moving:  `00004EF0 9A3404EF03 call 0x3ef:0x434`.  the 9A opcode is call far absolute. https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/call

Comment: @RufusVS: Oh, I see you were talking about just the `call far` itself.  But unless you put a `nop` *after* it, the address of every later instruction changes, too.  ((Update: apparently they are, I missed that detail).  There are near calls across it, e.g. changing what's at the `call 0x5038` target will obviously break the program.  (To actually save space, you'd want to disassemble with `objconv` into NASM syntax to get labels for branch targets, then re-assemble, to get updated targets for near jumps.)

Comment: To Rufus and Peter Cordes, thank you both for the replies.

Comment: 16 bit, many tools cannot be used

Answer (score 2):

DOS doesn't load programs at a constant address so the far calls have relocation entries that also need changing, if one is modifying an executable.

Also the moved `call` instruction may be the destination of a `call` or `jmp` instruction which also needs changing.

Comment: 1) So how or where can I find the relocation entries? 2) So far I have not reached there, the first attempt to do call 0x3ef:0x434 is already wrong, but given the context of the function it should highly not call the instruction at that location as the two pushes of ax are needed.